# Isomorphism preserves conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $f$ be an isomorphism such that $f: G\to G'$. For each $a\in G$, I need to show that $f (\text {cl}_G(a))=cl_{G'}(f(a))$ for $a$.

I write the definition of conjugacy:

$cl_G(a)=\{b \mid b=cac^{-1}\}, c\in G$,

Now, 
$f(cl_G(a))= \big\{f(b) \mid f(b)=f(c)f(a)f(c^{-1})\big\} $,

How do I proceed from here?

Any hints would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's kind of an unusual way to write the conjugacy class; is $c$ fixed, where is it coming from, etc. Would things be better if you used $cl_G(a) = \{cac^{-1} : c \in G\}$?

Comment: @pjs36 that is the definition the book gives so I need to stick with that that

Comment: OK, then write out $cl_{G'}(f(a))$ and compare it to the $f(cl_G(a))$ that you already have. There will just be two small differences that you'll have to reconcile.

Comment: @pjs36 can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: It probably is better to focus on the set that is described using the given notation for conjugacy class, and then apply the isomorphism to each element of the set, rather than focusing on the notation used. Incidentally, the way you have placed the set brackets may be causing you confusion: the conjugacy class of $a$ is better written as $\{cac^{-1} : c \in G \}$.

Comment: @pjs36 - you are right. I've deleted my ridiculous misunderstanding. My apologies to Jennie Durham for it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think the real lesson here is that everybody is tripped up by that notation for the conjugacy class :P

Comment: Still my interpretation had $cl_G(a)$ as simply the singleton set $\{cac^{-1}\}$ for given $c$ and $a$. SInce I know what a conjugacy class is, you'd think I would have recognized that was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I really dislike the notation here.

But if we've established that $f(\operatorname{cl}_G(a)) = \{f(b): f(b) = f(c)f(a)f(c^{-1})\}$, it should be a small leap to use the properties of homomorphisms to move the inverse outside of $f$, and write

$$f(\operatorname{cl}_G(a)) = \{f(b): f(b) = f(c)f(a)f(c)^{-1}\}.$$

How does this compare to $$\operatorname{cl}_{G'}(f(a)) = \{x: x = yf(a)y^{-1}\},$$

using the definition of $\operatorname{cl}_{G'}(f(a))$, where $x,y \in G'$? Because remember: in the original definition of the conjugacy class of $a$, the $b$ and $c$ were just dummy variables. Here $x$ and $y$ are the equivalent dummy variables in $G'$.

Well, since $x, y \in G'$, with $f: G \to G'$ a bijection (among other things), we can write $x = f(b)$ and $y = f(c)$ without loss of generality, because $x, y, b,$ and $c$ are all just dummy variables.

---

Again, I would **strongly** encourage you to get used to thinking of a conjugacy class as, for example, $\operatorname{cl}_G(a) = \{gag^{-1} : g \in G\}$ the set of things you get as you conjugate $a$ by all the elements in your group; as (our dummy variable) $g$ "runs over" $G$. It's just really bad form for the book to use an unqualified variable in a formula like that, that makes things confusing. It's also confusing to give the result of conjugation (originally $b$) a name when we never really need to refer to that name, it's just "some conjugate" of $a$. The lack of qualifiers/quantifiers is just really confusing in the original.

In "the standard" version of the proof, it'll turn out that as $c$ "runs over" $G$, it'll be obvious that $f(c)$ "runs over" $G'$:

$$f(\operatorname{cl}_G(a)) = \{f(c)f(a)f(c)^{-1} : c \in G\} = \{f(c)f(a)f(c)^{-1} : f(c) \in G'\} = \operatorname{cl}_{G'}(f(a)).$$